# vmware player fails to install but no errors given

Tags: vmware

I am trying to install VMware player onto my workstation (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS).  I've followed the instructions for installing from a bundle (download, chmod and sudo ./bundle_file) after which the installation process goes through a number of steps and finishes without any obvious errors.  Despite there being no errors, closer scrutiny of the output seems to suggest that the installation did not actually install.

command ran as follows:

```
sudo ./VMware-Player-15.5.0-14665864.x86_64.bundle

Extracting VMware Installer...done.
Installing VMware Player Setup 15.5.0
Copying files...
Rolling back VMware Player Setup 15.5.0
Removing files...
Deconfiguring...
```

The attempted installation takes approx 9 seconds.

The **complete** installation log is as follows:
/tmp/vmware-root/vmware-vmis-20775.log

```
2019-09-23T13:13:06.271+09:30| host-20775| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2019-09-23T13:13:06.271+09:30| host-20775| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2019-09-23T13:13:06.271+09:30| host-20775| I125: Host is Linux 4.15.0-64-generic Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
2019-09-23T13:13:06.270+09:30| host-20775| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2019-09-23T13:13:06.270+09:30| host-20775| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2019-09-23T13:13:06.270+09:30| host-20775| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
```

No vmplayer command is created anywhere that I can find.

I've also tried downloading and running the full workstation bundle (VMware-Workstation-Full-15.5.0-14665864.x86_64.bundle).  Output of the run attempt is nearly identical (only the name changes).

I've spent many hours crawling through Q&A forums and cannot find a similar case.  Anyone know how to fix this?  I need the vmplayer working asap.

Comment: Same problem in Linux Mint (Tina). And really don't see the point in downvoting.

Comment: Same problem in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with VMware Workstation 15.5.2, here I have Rolling back VMware Installer 3.0.0 and I don't find useful logfiles with it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides doing a complete manual reinstall as described [here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/38), consider checking if you've disabled all other hypervisor kernel modules such as

```
$ lsmod | grep vm
kvm_intel             217088  0
kvm                   610304  1 kvm_intel
```

and removing them (with sudo)

```
modprobe -r kvm_intel
modprobe -r kvm
```